# Audiokit: EZMicrophone + AKOscillator AKMixer

Tags: audiokit

I'm using Audio Kit to see it will make life easier... and here's my problem:
I'm using EZ Microphone because it gives me a nice buffer that I can stick in a circular queue and analyze.

That works fine until I also start up some oscillators and plug them into the mixer, and make that output the AudioKit.output. Then, I can get my beeps, but the Mic stops feeding me data (with no notification, BTW).
It works fine in the simulator, just not on the device.

I might be able to use AKMicrophone and tap its output, but it's not as nice as getting a block that I can just shovel into the circular queue .

Advice?

Answer (score 0):

AudioKit's AKMicrophoneTracker uses EZMicrophone under the hood, but I am not sure if it plays well with using a regular AudioKit signal chain at the same time.  Maybe it will do the same thing you're experiencing. Barring that I do think tapping the microphone is the best solution. Sorry its not quite as elegant as the other way, but it is pretty useful if you also want to process the microphone beforehand, perhaps adding filters that aid in preprocessing your data.

Comment: Thanks Aurelius! Who'd know better than you!

Comment: Do you have an idea why it works in the simulator but not on an iPad? I am setting the session to 
`[AKSettings  setSessionWithCategory:SessionCategoryPlayAndRecord with:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:&error ]`